# Android 14 'Accessibility' Restricted keylogger permission

Tags: android

In Android 14, the keylogger service permission is automatically disabled when our application gets an update.

Requirement: 
Our users do not want to enable the keylogger service permission again once they update our application.

[image: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXxlvl.png)]

Is there any option for not disabling the keylogger service permission or is there any manual work around needed?